# regex for MAC address

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following that I'm using to check for a valid MAC address

```
function isMacValid(mac) {
    var regexMac = /^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$/i
    return regexMac.test(mac);
}
```

This works for MAC addresses that match the standard of 6 hex values separated by either a hyphen or colon... `1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f` or `e7-f8-90-0a-1b`

I now need to account for another non-standard notation of just 6 sets of hex with no separators... so `1a2b3c4d5e6f` would be acceptable. How do I now make the : or - optional?

Comment: `[:-]?` instead of just `[:-]`

Comment: wooo... 13 seconds for an answer... got to be a record!

Comment: @Pointy... works a treat... mark it up as an answer and I'll accept when I'm able to do so.... Thanks

Comment: Note that @Pointy's change will permissively match submissions with only partial use of separators (e.g., `0123:4567:89AB`), but your current working solution already permissively matches on inconsistent separators (e.g. `01-23-45:67:89-AB`) so it's probably not an issue for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `[:-]?` instead of `[:-]`.

The only problem is that 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e6f and 1a-2b:3c:4d:5e:6f will pass the check. So to avoid that I suggest you to change :

```
var regexMac = /^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$/i
```

with

```
var regexMac = /^((([0-9A-F]{2}:){5})|(([0-9A-F]{2}-){5})|([0-9A-F]{10}))([0-9A-F]{2})$/i
```

It's less beautifull but works

Comment: The second alternative can just be `[0-9A-F]{12}`

Comment: Good idea but it won't work because we need `[0-9A-F]{2}` for `-` and `:`

Comment: I meant the alternative with no separators.

Comment: Yes but unfortunately the author of the question need all alternative in his regex. So it makes very difficult to simply the syntax

Comment: I don't understand. You have one alternative with `:`, another alternative with `-`, and a third alternative with no separator. The one with no separator is just 12 hex digits, it doesn't need to be grouped.

Comment: Ok so here's your solution : `^((([0-9A-F]{2}:){5})|(([0-9A-F]{2}-){5}))([0-9A-F]{2})|([0-9A-F]{12})$`. As you can see we didn't simplify much but you realized to me that `{2}){5}` can be simplified with `{10}`. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var regexMac = /^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}\W){6}$/i
```